# Running a local script on remote server over ssh with sudo privileges

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, sudo, remote

I have a script `script.sh` on local machine which I want to execute on remote server with sudo permissions. I am logging in to remote server through SSH and executing the script using the below command

```
cat ./script.sh | sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@ip
```

How can I make such that the sudo for running the script takes the password pass from this command only instead of creating an another script .